# Whats the meaning of "countertops" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Anthralin is a topical medication used in treatment of psoriasis. I took the following text from online article.

Anthralin. This medication is believed to normalize DNA activity in skin cells. Anthralin (Dritho-Scalp) can also remove scale, making the skin smoother. However, anthralin can irritate skin, and it stains virtually anything it touches, including skin, clothing, **countertops** and bedding. For that reason doctors often recommend short-contact treatment — allowing the cream to stay on your skin for a brief time before washing it off. Anthralin is sometimes used in combination with ultraviolet light.

*countertop* means *top surface of the basin*, but it has no connection to the above context.

Answer (score 3):

Here it means:

*"The flat working surface on top of waist-level kitchen cabinets."*

See [countertop](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/countertop)

Here it is used as an item in a list of things that can easily be stained.